# Gitlab and git user

Tags: git, bash, gitlab

I just installed gitlab ce on my server. It's an already apache running server. 
First issue, was to change the port to not conflict with gitlab. Great.
Now, gitlab automatically created its own git user, the problem is that I already had a git user. Now each time I log in through ssh, instead of going through my regular created git user home folder, it goes into `/var/opt/gitlab`.

So what's happening. Plus, the whole bash is completely different, only shows `$`, I know it can be fixed with `.bash_rc ~/profile` but still.

Is there anyway to fix this scramble.

Also, I have another question, Is it possible to use my apache server and configure a virtualhost instead of creating a whole new server running alongside with a different port ?

**EDIT 1**

For installing on apache if you have apache and therefore save resources without having 2 instance of webserver running and have a nice `git.yourdomain.com`
Follow this tutorial here: http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs about changing gitlab's default git user/group:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/README.md#changing-the-name-of-the-git-user-group

This link is in the `gitlab.rb` config file, btw.  :-)

Comment: I didn't want to do that though because in the documentation, it warned about unexpected behavior...

Comment: What was the existing `git` user being used for? Can you just move whatever that `git` user was doing to some other user? It sounds like you were using it for interactive login, which smells a bit funny: the `git` user is traditionally a non-interactive user account that only uses `git-shell` to run git commands, even without gitlab in the mix.

Comment: I didnt know there was a tradition behind the user git, In fact, the user git hosted my repository and I gave it an interactive shell because I like my shell to be coloured especially since I was going through the .git to create some `hook` scripts. I guess I can remove the `git` user now since I transferred the repo to `gitlab`. Anyways, it was the first time I have seen `.deb` rewrites a user and modify the home folder location. I was quite surprised.